# Why does content not appear in bsModal when coming from server?

Tags: r, triggers, shiny, bootstrap-modal, shinyjs

For some reason the displaying of bsModal content seems to go wrong when it is triggered by an `observeEvent` from the server side, images and or text don't appear, and it also seems to cause a disabling of `Sweetalerts` in some cases (which are basically prebuild modals).

*I tagged `shinyjs` for this reason, since the app includes interaction with it. 
Besides a very long post, and complicated issue, I hope that the `bsmodal` part as well as the `sweetalert` coding with `shinyJS`, which is a copy of work by Dean Attali may help some other people who happen to read this. If you find it useful, give the post an upvote.*

A full app with scenario 1, 2 and 3 is found below. 
Scenarios 4 and further are not in the full app, because some cause other parts of the app to stop working as well as soon as you add their code.
I suggest to try the app at the end, and then read through my scenarios. (tried to make it as clear as possible.)

I'm using `bsModals` to add new functionality to my `Shiny` program (very large complex app), and discovered something strange while trying to incorporate images into `bsmodals`. I did some research into when the problem occurs, and present a test app here with several scenarios.

## My primary issue:

For my purposes I need to figure out why scenario 7b doesn't work, i.e. bsmodal from server with image and observeEvent to activate it, 
**2nd main question** is, can you somehow code the `trigger = input$button1` argument in the bsmodal as `trigger = values$variable` somehow? I tried this but could not figure it out.

*The main problem seems to revolve around the difference in behaviour of `trigger =` argument inside `bsmodal()` versus using `observeEvent()` with `toggleModal()`*

## Scenario 1: works

This on the UI side for instance works fine:

i.e. the `modal` appears, and the `sweetalert` in the app shows up on start

```
 actionButton("show1", "Show modal 1"),
 bsModal(id= 'InfoModal1',title = "This modal works", trigger = "show1", "triggered by clicking button 1, trigger argument in UI code for bsModal without image"),
```

## Scenario 2:  works

Adding an image to the modal, still all through UI side, works fine, image appears:

```
 actionButton("show2", "Show modal 2"),
 bsModal(id= 'InfoModal2',title = "This modal works", trigger = "show2",
                  img(src="https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png", width="550", height="200"),
                  br(), "triggered by clicking button 2, trigger argument in UI code for bsModal"),
```

## Scenario 3:  works partially

Now we try to have it triggered by the server side of things. Which is usefull if it is for instance needed to have a modal that doesn't come from a button click, but a variable value changing. The modal appears, and this variation doesn't cause problems with the sweetalert, but no text content in the modal body!

ui side:

```
 actionButton("show3", "Show modal 3"),
 bsModal(id= 'InfoModal3',title = "This modal works but content text does NOT show up!", "triggered by clicking button 3, and use observeEvent in the server, without image"),
```

server side:

```
observeEvent(input$show3, { toggleModal(session, "InfoModal3", toggle = "toggle")  })
```

## Scenario 4:  does not work at all, and sweetalert now broken too

If I add an image to scenario 3, it's the same result. To do this I add the following code behind the senario 3 code in the UI and a second observer to the server, **and I also notice, that if I don't run rm(UI) first, most of the time the ui will be wrong, i.e. without button nr 4**

ui side

```
 actionButton("show4", "Show modal 4"),
          bsModal(id= 'InfoModal4',title = "This modal works but content image does NOT show up!", img(src="https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png", width="550", height="200"),"triggered by clicking button 4, trigger modal by observeEvent in the server, without image")
```

server side:

```
observeEvent(input$show4, { toggleModal(session, "InfoModal4", toggle = "toggle")  })
```

## Scenario 5: WORKS  -> build basic `bsModal` with `renderUI()` with trigger in it from the server side

replace whole `tabitems()` section in working app with this in the UI:

```
tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'tab1',
              actionButton("show5", "Show modal 5"),
              uiOutput("MyModal5")
    ))))
```

and replace server with:

```
server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  shinyjs::js$swal( title = '<span style="color:#339FFF; font-size: 30px">Finished loading app<span>',
                    text = '<span style="color:black; font-size: 16px">version: 1.0.0 <br> written by: M.A. van Dijk<span>',
                    imageUrl= "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png" )

  output$MyModal5 <- renderUI({  bsModal(id= 'InfoModal5',title = "This modal works but content text does NOT show up!", trigger = "show5", " build by server, and triggered by clicking button 5 with trigger argument in modal, without image") })
}
```

## Scenario 6: works with or without image, but.....

ui part is :

```
tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'tab1',
              actionButton("show6", "Show modal 6"),
              uiOutput("MyModal6")
    ))))
```

server part after the swal function:

```
 output$MyModal6 <- renderUI({ bsModal(id= 'InfoModal6',title = "This modal works and content text does show up!", trigger = "show6", " build by server, and triggered by clicking button 6 and an observeEvent in the server, without image") })
 }
```

or the version of server WITH image:

```
output$MyModal6 <- renderUI({ bsModal(id= 'InfoModal6',title = "This modal works and content text does show up!", trigger = "show6", img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png", width="550", height="200"),  
                      "build by server, and triggered by clicking button 6 and a trigger argument in the bsmodal, with image") })
```

*I can't use this in my program however when I want to have the modal triggered by a variable rather than a button click. To do that, I should use an observeEvent like the next scenario, I think. Unless there is a way  to use "trigger = "some reactive value" *

## Scenario 7: Works, without an image, not with....

I found out that it does work with an `observeEvent(input$show7)` instead of `trigger = "show7"`  in the dummy app to do everything from the server, until I add an img(scr.... part. 
ui side:

```
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = 'tab1',
          actionButton("show7", "Show modal 7"),
          uiOutput("MyModal7")
))))
```

server side

```
output$MyModal7 <- renderUI({ bsModal(id= 'InfoModal7',title = "This modal works and content text does show up!", "build by server, and triggered by clicking button 7 and a trigger argument in the bsmodal, with image") })

  observeEvent(input$show7, { toggleModal(session, "InfoModal7", toggle = "toggle")  })
```

.
.To add the image, replace the output$modal7 with

```
output$MyModal7 <- renderUI({ bsModal(id= 'InfoModal7',title = "This modal doesn't work",                                   img(src="https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png", width="550", height="200"),
                                        "build by server, and triggered by clicking button 7 and a trigger argument in the bsmodal, with image") })
```

.
.
.

**WORKING APP FOR Scenario 1, 2 and 3:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.swal = function(params) { 
  var defaultParams = {
title: null,
text : null,
imageUrl: null
};
params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
swal({title : params.title, text : params.text,  imageUrl : params.imageUrl,
imageSize: '400x400',  
html: true,
showCancelButton : false,
showConfirmButton : true,
closeOnConfirm: true,
confirmButtonColor: '#339FFF',
allowOutsideClick: true   }); };"

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Dummy App"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.js"),   ### code for the sweetalerts
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",                                                  ### code for the sweetalerts
                href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.css")    ### code for the sweetalerts
        ),

  sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
                menuItem("My Tab", tabName = 'tab1'))),

  dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),     ### code for the sweetalerts
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jscode),  ### code for the sweetalerts

    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'tab1',

          actionButton("show1", "Show modal 1"),
          bsModal(id= 'InfoModal1',title = "This modal works", trigger = "show1", "triggered by clicking button 1, trigger argument in UI code for bsModal without image"),

          actionButton("show2", "Show modal 2"),
          bsModal(id= 'InfoModal2',title = "This modal works", trigger = "show2",
                  img(src="https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png", width="550", height="200"),
                  br(), "triggered by clicking button 2, trigger argument in UI code for bsModal"),

          actionButton("show3", "Show modal 3"),    

          bsModal(id= 'InfoModal3',title = "This modal works but content text does NOT show up!", "triggered by clicking button 3, trigger modal by observeEvent in the server, without image")

      ))))

server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  shinyjs::js$swal( title = '<span style="color:#339FFF; font-size: 30px">Finished loading app<span>',
                     text = '<span style="color:black; font-size: 16px">version: 1.0.0 <br> written by: M.A. van Dijk<span>',
                     imageUrl= "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png" )

    observeEvent(input$show3, { toggleModal(session, "InfoModal3", toggle = "toggle")  })


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```